# smart contract issue

Tags: metamask

hi I accidentally sent it eth to a eth smart contract from my exodus wallet instead of sending it to my metal mask and sending it from there is there any way to retrieve and withdraw this money back to my Exodus please thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you meant to send Ethers to a wallet but you accidentally sent them to some contract.

If your transaction was successful (not reverted) it means the contract has a `payable` function which accepts Ethers. So it was expecting someone to send it Ethers. Therefore it may also have functionality to send Ethers back to some place.

Basically you either have to read the contract code or contact whoever owns the contract. It's impossible to say without seeing the contract code.